# Performing Post SQL query on result set?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically what I want to do can be put neatly in the following two steps.

1. Execute a query on a particular table. I then get the result set.
2. One of the columns in the result set say 'id' has only numbers in it. I would want to take this number
   'id' in every row in the result set, join it with another table called ID_NAMES & replace the 
   individual ids of every row with corresponding names obtained by joining with ID_NAMES table.

In a sense this is like performing post SQL query on the result set I obtain from executing pre SQL query.

Is there anyway I can accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks edited my tags, for simplicity lets say MySQL, although I would like it work on DB2 as well.

Comment: Can't you just join on the table whose names you want to use? (joining on the ID)

Comment: Are you familiar with JOINS in SQL? `SELECT table1.id, table2.name FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id` should do the trick. Is there any reason why you are wanting to do this after you get the results back from table1?

Comment: @Adam, I cant join because that particular column may or many not be included in the result set. It all depends on how the condition tree of the persistence layer generates the sql.

Comment: Join might probably do the trick. I will have to try it out. Its certainly not a straightforward scenario, but it might just do the trick here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.name FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

Try this query....
Refer at  [JNevill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221001/jnevill)

Comment: Yeah that might do the trick. I was under impression that simple join may not work out here. But it might.